# Recaptcha::Recaptcha Error - No site key specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recaptcha

I am working on a MVC project in Ruby on Rails. I have the actual code and i have to understand it in next few days and then try to upgrade it.

I have a home-page with a textbox which ask you the e-mail for resistration. The problem is that when i push the submit button it gives me

> Recaptcha::Recaptcha Error  -   No site key specified

I know that there are many posts about this problem but i don't manage to resolve it.

Here is my .env file

```
RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=6Lc6BAAAAAAAAChqRbQZcn_yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY=6Lc6BAAAAAAAAKN3DRm6VA_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_KEY=false
OMNIAUTH_PROVIDER_SECRET=false
ADMIN_NAME=false
SECRET_KEY_BASE=false
GA_PROVIDER_KEY=false
TWILIO_SID=false
TWILIO_TOKEN=false
TWILIO_NUMBER=false
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure recaptcha to pull the keys from your secrets.yml by adding an initializer file, config/initializers/recaptcha.rb:

```
# config/initializers/recaptcha.rb
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.site_key   = Rails.application.secrets[:RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY]
  config.secret_key = Rails.application.secrets[:RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY]
  # Uncomment the following line if you are using a proxy server:
  # config.proxy = 'http://myproxy.com.au:8080'
end
```

End in secrets.yml RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY and RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY make sure that it is written in capital letters